# Asp.net MVC / MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

This script works well in MVC 1, however I get "invalid arguments error" in MVC2:
this.menuItems.Add("action", Html.ActionLink("action", "view", "Controller"));

Comment: What is the class type of menuitems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC2, [ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493018.aspx) returns an [MvcHtmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring.aspx), and menuItems.Add likely expects a string. So this should work:

```
this.menuItems.Add("action",
  Html.ActionLink("action", "view", "Controller").ToString());
```

Comment: Does anyone else find it strange that MvcHtmlString doesn't include an implicit conversion operator for string?

Comment: @user373721. No problem. (May I ask that you mark it as the answer. Thanks.)

Comment: How can I do that, I searched but did not find an answer, thanks

Comment: @Jordan that was a concious decision. Implicit conversion operators can be confusing and we wanted to enforce the difference between encoded and unencoded html strings.

Comment: @user373721. It's a checkbox underneath the vote control. No prob if you can't find it.

Comment: @marcind. Thanks for the info. (Although, looking at MvcHtmlString in Reflector, there doesn't seem to be a difference between ToString and ToHtmlString.)

Comment: They are the same because it's not those two methods that are responsible for the behavior, but rather consumers like `HttpUtiliy.HtmlEncode`. The reason why ToString is there at all is because it's a virtual method coming from `Object` that was overriden to provide a better debugging experience.